# How many ways to deal with the integral $\int \frac{d x}{1-\sin x \cos x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Multiplying both numerator and denominator of the integrand by $\sec^2 x$ yields
\begin{aligned}
& \int \frac{d x}{1-\sin x \cos x} \\
=& \int \frac{\sec ^{2} x}{\sec ^{2} x-\tan x} d x \\
=& \int \frac{d(\tan x)}{\tan ^{2} x-\tan x+1} \\
=& 2 \int \frac{d(2 \tan x-1)}{(2 \tan x-1)^{2}+(\sqrt{3})^{2}} \\
=& \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \arctan\left(\frac{2 \tan x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+C .
\end{aligned}
Is there any simpler solution? Let me know if you have any, thank you for your attention.

Wish you enjoy the solution!

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-\cos(x)\sin(x)}=\frac{2}{2-\sin(2x)}$ then make the substitution $x=\arctan(t)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use the double-angle formula for sine,

$$\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$$

and then get

$$\newcommand{\II}{\mathcal{I}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\II := \int \frac{\dd x}{1 - \sin x \cos x} =  \int \frac{\dd x}{1 - \frac 1 2 \sin 2x} =2 \int \frac{\dd x}{2 - \sin 2x}$$

Then let $u = 2x$ to get

$$\II = \int \frac{\dd u}{2 - \sin u}$$

[Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) ($t = \tan(u/2)$) then gives

$$\II = \int \frac{1}{2 - \frac{2t}{1+t^2}} \frac{2}{1+t^2} \, \dd t = \int \frac{\dd t}{t^2 - t + 1}$$

[Integral $(13)$ from this PDF](http://integral-table.com/downloads/single-page-integral-table.pdf) then gives the answer

$$\II 
= \frac{2}{\sqrt 3} \arctan \left( \frac{2t - 1}{\sqrt 3} \right) + C 
= \frac{2}{\sqrt 3} \arctan \left( \frac{2 \tan(x) - 1}{\sqrt 3} \right) + C $$

Comment: Since the substitution is $t=\tan x$, there was never a need to work with $u$ or $\sin2x$. One can jump to this choice of $t$ with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules).

Comment: Nice solution :-) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

another method:

$\sin(x) = \frac{tan(x)}{sec(x)}$ and $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{sec(x)}$

now you have to do u-substitution and complete the square.