# Is it easy to evaluate the integral $\int \frac{\sin ^{5} x+\cos ^{5} x}{\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x} d x$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Splitting the integral into two by division:
$$
I:=\int \frac{\sin ^{5} x+\cos ^{5} x}{\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x} d x=\int\left(\sin ^{2} x+\cos ^{2} x-\frac{\sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x(\sin x+\cos x)}{\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x}\right)dx
$$

Simplifying gives
$$
I=x-\int \frac{\sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x}{1-\sin x \cos x} d x
$$
By [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4344864/732917),
$$\int \frac{\sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x}{1-\sin x \cos x} d x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \tan x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-x+\frac{\cos 2 x}{4}+C_2$$
Now we can conclude that $$I=2x+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-2 \tan x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\frac{\cos 2 x}{4}+C$$
*checked by [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB%28sin%5E%285%29x%2Bcos%5E5%28x%29%29%2F%28cos%5E3%2Bsin%5E3x%29) .

How about when the power 5 is replaced by a ***higher one***?

Comment: Indeed, *Mathematica* gives:  $$2 x-\frac{1}{4} \cos (2 x)+\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-2 \tan
   (x)}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$
I_{n}:=\int \frac{\sin ^{n} x+\cos ^{n} x}{\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x} d x
$$
After getting the answer for the integral $I_5$, I started to investigate the integral with higher powers $n$.  In a couple of days, I found a reduction formula for it.

For any natural number $n\geq 4$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin ^{n} x+\cos ^{n} x=&\left(\sin ^{2} x+\cos ^{2} x\right)\left(\sin ^{n-2} x+\cos ^{n-2} x\right) -\sin ^{2} x \cos ^{n-2} x-\cos ^{2} x \sin ^{n-2} x.
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\frac{\sin ^{n} x+\cos ^{n} x}{\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x}=\frac{\sin ^{n-2} x+\cos ^{n-2} x}{\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x}-\frac{\sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x\left(\sin ^{n-4} x+\cos ^{n-4} x\right)}{\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x}
$$
We got a reduction formula for $I_n.$
$$
I_{n}=I_{n-2}-\int \frac{\sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x\left(\sin ^{n-4} x+\cos ^{n-4} x\right)}{\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x} d x
$$

As an example, let’s start with $I_7$
$$
\begin{aligned}I_{7}&=I_{5}-\int \sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x d x\\&= 2x+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-2 \tan x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\frac{\cos (2 x)}{4} -\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{1-\cos (4 x)}{2} d x\\&= \frac{15x}{8} +\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-2 \tan x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\frac{\cos (2 x)}{4} +\frac{\sin (4x)}{32} +C
\end{aligned}$$
For $I_9,$ we use division instead of the reduction formula.

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{9} &=\int \frac{\left(\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x\right)\left(\sin ^{6} x-\sin ^{3} x \cos ^{3} x+\cos ^{6} x\right)}{\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x} d x \\
&=\underbrace{\int \left(\sin ^{6} x+\cos ^{6} x \right) d x}_{J}-\underbrace{\int \sin ^{3} x \cos ^{3} x d x}_{K}
\end{aligned}
$$

For the integral $J$, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin ^{6} x+\cos ^{6} x &=\left(\sin ^{2} x+\cos ^{2} x\right)\left(\sin ^{4} x-\sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x+\cos ^{4} x\right) \\
&=\left(\sin ^{2} x+\cos ^{2} x\right)^{2}-3 \sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x \\
&=1-\frac{3}{4} \sin ^{2}(2 x) \\
&=1-\frac{3}{8}(1-\cos (4 x) )\\
&=\frac{1}{8}(5+3 \cos (4 x))
\end{aligned}
$$
We get
$$
J=\frac{1}{8}\left(5 x+\frac{3 \sin (4 x)}{4}\right)+C_{1}
$$

For $K$, using the double-angle formula yields

$$
\begin{aligned}
K &=\int \sin ^{3} x \cos ^{3} x d x \\
&=\frac{1}{8} \int \sin ^{3}(2 x) d x \\
&=-\frac{1}{16} \int\left(1-\cos ^{2}(2 x)\right) d(\cos 2 x) \\
&=-\frac{1}{16}\left(\cos (2 x)-\frac{\cos ^{3}(2 x)}{3}\right)+C_2
\end{aligned}
$$

Now we can conclude that

$$
I_{9}=\frac{1}{96}\left[60 x+9 \sin (4 x)-6 \cos (2 x)+2 \cos ^{3}(2 x)\right]+C
$$

By the reduction formula, we now dare to find $I_{11}.$

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{11} &=I_{9}-\int \frac{\sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x\left(\sin ^{5} x+\cos ^{5} x\right)}{\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x} d x \\
&=I_{9}-\int \sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x\left(1-\frac{\sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x}{1-\sin x \cos x}\right) d x \\
&=I_{9}- \underbrace{ \int \sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x d x}_{L}+\underbrace{\int \frac{\sin ^{4} x \cos ^{4} x}{1-\sin x \cos x}}_{M} d x
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
L &=\frac{1}{4} \int \sin ^{2}(2 x) d x=\frac{1}{8} \int(1-\cos 4 x) d x =\frac{1}{8}\left(x-\frac{\sin (4 x)}{4}\right)+C_{1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Using the formula in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4344864/732917), we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
M=& \int \frac{\sin ^{4} x \cos ^{4} x}{1-\sin x \cos x} d x \\
=& \int \frac{\sin ^{3} x \cos ^{3} x}{1-\sin x \cos x} d x-\int \sin ^{3} x \cos ^{3} x d x \\
=& \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \tan x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\frac{9}{8} x+\frac{\cos 2 x}{4}+\frac{\sin 4 x}{32} +\frac{1}{16}\left[\cos (2 x)-\frac{\cos ^{3}(2 x)}{3}\right]+C . \\
=& \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \tan x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\frac{9}{8} x +\frac{\sin 4 x}{32} +\frac{5}{16} \cos (2 x)-\frac{1}{48} \cos ^{3}(2 x)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Grouping the integral together yields

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{11}=& \frac{1}{96}\left[-36 x+15 \sin (4 x)+29\cos (2 x)\right] +\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \tan x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Can you help me go ***further***?